# How to apply style_loader_src filter with exclusion of a specific file?

Tags: plugin-development

I am trying to remove query string from all scripts and styles files except on a specific with handle name `child-style` file but keep getting error of

> Missing argument 2 for _remove_q_strings()

with the following code

```
function _remove_q_strings($src, $handle){
   if($handle != 'child-style'){
     $src = remove_query_arg('ver', $src);
   }
   return $src;
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_q_strings', 15, 1 );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_q_strings', 15, 1);
```

Why giving me this while those two arguments a defined in the `apply_filters` [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php#L354)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last value of add_filter sets how many arguments are passed to your function.
You can pass two arguments like this:

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_q_strings', 15, 2 );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_q_strings', 15, 2 );
```

More details in the [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)